# Pandas Dataframe to Excel : no data from web scraping gets exported to excel

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from openpyxl import Workbook
import time
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import ExcelWriter

# initial value for table data 
total = []
result = []

#initial setting for excel file
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet()
filename = '/Users/sungyeon/Desktop/projects/text.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename)

#setting of crawling
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
target_url = 'https://price.joinsland.joins.com/theme/index_theme.asp?sisaegbn=T05'
driver.get(target_url)

# selection of first dropbox
select1 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='sido']"))))
select1.options[0].click()
# selection of second dropbox
select2 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='gugun']"))))

# for loop for values of second dropbox
for i in range(0,3):
    try:
        select2.options[i].click()
        title = select2.options[i].text
        wb.create_sheet(title)
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn_search').click()


# in case of stale element reference error 
    except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
        select2 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='gugun']"))))
        select2.options[i].click()
        title = select2.options[i].text
        wb.create_sheet(title)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn_search').click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# setting of table data from crawled webpage 
driver.current_url
table = driver.find_element_by_class_name('tbl_box')
tbody = table.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
rows=tbody.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

# making lists of data from crawled data    
for index, value in enumerate(rows):
    body = value.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    print('ok5')
    for i in range(len(body)):
        try: 
            data = body[i].text
            result.append(data)

        except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            body = value.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
            continue

    # adding data of a row to list of final dataset
    total.append(result)
    # clearing temp list
    result=[]
    time.sleep(2)   

# to create a new sheet named after the name of dropbox value 
# forming dataframe from list of dataset
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(total)
# converting to excel file into the sheet named after the name of dropbox value
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = title)
writer.save()
wb.save(filename=filename)
```

I have tried web-scraping using selenium.
data collecting part works fine
but the problem is I get no data exported to the excel file.
File, sheet creation are done well but I still get no data written on each sheet
I guess it may have something to do with indentation but can't figure it out. Or
any tips would be appreciated! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few issues found

- Indentation was missing for row loop
- Variable wb was not needed and caused the empty worksheet to be saved
- Totals initialization could be placed better

Here's the working code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from openpyxl import Workbook
import time
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import ExcelWriter

#initial setting for excel file
filename = '/Users/sungyeon/Desktop/projects/text.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename)

#setting of crawling
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
target_url = 'https://price.joinsland.joins.com/theme/index_theme.asp?sisaegbn=T05'
driver.get(target_url)

# selection of first dropbox
select1 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='sido']"))))
select1.options[0].click()
# selection of second dropbox
select2 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='gugun']"))))

# for loop for values of second dropbox
for i in range(0,3):
    total = [] # total for this dropbox value
    try:
        select2.options[i].click()
        title = select2.options[i].text
        #wb.create_sheet(title)
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn_search').click()


# in case of stale element reference error 
    except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
        select2 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='gugun']"))))
        select2.options[i].click()
        title = select2.options[i].text
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn_search').click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    # setting of table data from crawled webpage 
    driver.current_url
    table = driver.find_element_by_class_name('tbl_box')
    tbody = table.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
    rows = tbody.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

    # making lists of data from crawled data    
    for index, value in enumerate(rows):
        body = value.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        result=[]  # total for row
        for i in range(len(body)):
            try: 
                data = body[i].text
                result.append(data)

            except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
                body = value.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
                continue

        # adding data of a row to list of final dataset
        total.append(result)
        # clearing temp list
        time.sleep(2)   

# to create a new sheet named after the name of dropbox value 
# forming dataframe from list of dataset
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(total)
# converting to excel file into the sheet named after the name of dropbox value
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = title)
writer.save()
```